# Safari renders font correctly when Chrome and Firefox do not on macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, safari

I've had an annoyance for a while when visiting websites in Chrome that use the Palatino font: lowercase `y` and `z` don't show at all, and lowercase `x` shows as a double quote (`"`). I just tried installing Firefox, and it does the same. Safari, however, renders the font correctly.

Chrome's rendered fonts utility shows that the font is from a local file. I've tried using the `atsutil` utility to delete the font cache with no success. Font Book shows the font correctly, and applications like TextEdit can use it with no issues.

I've had this problem for several years, at least back to El Capitan (I'm on Catalina 10.15.2). It's been a low-level annoyance all this time. I'd like to fix it, but have no idea why only Chrome and Firefox would have the problem in the first place.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chrome, but I know that a setting in Firefox allows you to use or not web fonts in webpages. Sometimes, unchecking the option, restarting Firefox, then re-enabling the option will purge the web font cache and load a clean set of fonts.

Alternately, you can download the font from the [editor's website](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/palatino-linotype) and install it manually (it'll detect your OS automatically, unless you're using a script blocker such  as NoScript or ScriptSafe; if you do, you'll have to authorize the whole page).

EDIT: you did use the "sudo atsutil databases -remove" command to clear the system font cache, didn't you? It requires admin rights.

Comment: Yes, I did use atsutil as you said. I also had no other windows besides Terminal open, and restarted my Mac immediately afterwards.

Comment: I tried again, just to confirm: close all windows, open a Terminal window, issue `sudo atsutil databases -remove` (which said it removed two files), then restart. Still corrupted.

Comment: Tried to boot in Safe Mode? Just boot it up, wait until all system processes are up and running, then reboot normally. Sometimes that's enough to clear corrupted system caches. Otherwise, you can also clear your other browsers cache entirely. Maybe that's where the problem lies. Finally, you ca use AppleJack (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15667/applejack), though it's lost a lot of functionalities since the advent of macOS (it was designed for OS X), it can still perform basic cleaning tasks on macOS in Single User Mode. Worth a try, won't hurt your Mac.

Comment: I'm running a patched Catalina on my Mac Pro 5,1, which won't start in safe mode...which I only learned after trying it. This problem's not related to the patch, though, as it happened in previous versions of macOS.

Comment: I were you, I'd try AppleJack in Single User mode (press Command-S on startup til you reach the prompt). Once there, type "applejack AUTO restart" (no quotes, AUTO in caps), wait til AJ is done, it'll reboot your Mac, but depending on the amount of data in your system and apps caches, virtual memory and the like, it could take some time. Repairing permissions won't work, so AJ will skip it altogether, though it'll pretend to do it. Like I said, can't hurt.

Comment: I can't get Single User mode to run either: I have a non-flashed RX560 card in the machine. I wound up using OnyX ( https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html ) to do the same thing. Still no luck.

Comment: You can try to uninstall Chrome via AppRemover. It'll perform an in-depth uninstall. Then you could re-install a clean copy of Chrome, preferably from the standalone installer instead of the web installer. Once you've installed it, go to Preferences and disable hardware acceleration. It's been known to create rendering problems on some sites that don't reload their font cache often enough.

Comment: Still no luck.

Does Chrome have its own font cache? Or is it depending on the OS to get it right? I can't think of anything else I can do on the OS side to make things work. And it's only this one font. Others work fine.

Comment: Do you have a link to one or several of those sites, just to check if I get the same problem?

Comment: The one that keeps irritating me is Gatestone Institute. Example: https://www.gatestoneinstitute.org/15774/european-union-the-end

Comment: On Firefox Dev Edition (latest build) in Windows 10, it renders perfectly. Scanning the source code of the page, I couldn't find any mention of Palatino as a font being used. What character set do you use? I'm on UTF-8, Latin languages. In Firefox, you can try to enforce the use of the fonts Firefox embarks, not the website's, by going to Settings, under Language and appearance, Advanced, and uncheck the box saying that you allow websites to use their own fonts instead of Firefox's.

Comment: I wound up buying a new Mac Mini and using Migration Assistant to move my data to it. (For other reasons, not this issue.) Guess what? The problem moved with it. AFAIK, I'm using UTF-8 Latin as well, but have never set it explicitly.

Comment: Well, it was bound to happen if you carbon (no pun intended) copied the content of your first Mac on the second one. Do you confirm that the problem still happens on Safari and Chrome, but not on Firefox?